# HTML date input showing date set via value="" incorrectly, off by one month

Tags: html, date, firefox, datepicker, chromium

i have tested this on two browsers

1.Chromium Version 76.0.3809.87

2.Mozilla firefox 68.0.1

whenever i set a date in date field in input in y-m-d format, the month gets decremented by 1 for no reason

this is my code

```html
<input type="date" name="some_date" id="some_date" value="2003-12-16">
```

this is rendered in the browser (both mozilla and chromium)

[image]

it should be displayed as 16/12/2003 but it is shown as 16/11/2003, is this a browser bug? how could i solve this?

Comment: Not my Chrome 74 nor my Fx 68.0.1 on Win 10

Comment: Agreed, your code works on Chrome version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 68.0.1 (64-bit) both Linux Mint 19.

Comment: Works perfectly on Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Something weird with your locale? What's your OS, what's the value of the input if you inspect it from JS?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this code and it will be fixed.

```
<input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="YYYY MM DD" value="2015-08-09">
```